# How can I check the output sampling frequency of a sound card in windows7

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

I have a USB sound card that claims to accept 192kHz as an output sampling frequency. When I connect it, a status LED shows 192kHz is active.

How can I check if windows7 is sending a 192kHz signal to this sound card to make sure that frequencies above my hearing range have a chance of getting through?

Comment: to ask the.. not so obvious, is this for audio or something else?

Comment: It's for FM radio. With 192kHz you can generate a complete FM signal with stereo signal & RDS radio text. If you broadcast this with a mono transmitter, it will play on your radio in stereo and show the station name and song info. As a side effect the result sounds much better than a cheap stereo transmitter.

Answer (score 3):

The only place where windows intervenes in the audio path is if the system mixer is being used.  The sample rate the system mixer uses is configured in the audio control panel (`mmsys.cpl`).

[image]

That being said, most applications which would inject RDS would use exclusive mode control of the soundcard, which requires the application to specify the sample rate and bit depth.

To be 100% sure, you would have to connect an oscilloscope to the sound card output, use a tone generator to play a 96kHz tone, and verify you are getting a 96 kHz signal out of the card.

Comment: As I currently have not oscilloscope available, before I go on a journey to find one: as a first step it would be good enough to check if the sound card reports to any windows7 application that sound is accepted at 192kHz sampling rate.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you I have used a software from Passmark

Link

https://www.passmark.com/products/soundcheck/

My sound card is not that powerful as yours at the following example below in picture it is currently outputting 128 KHz at 24 bit stereo sound 300 Hz sinewave. You can change stuff in here to check for your requirements.

[image]

192 KHz may show up in your card

My sound card only supports 128 KHz sampling rate maximum

To check this go to Settings -> View wave capabilities - Windows

Select I/O -> Output

Device -> Select the device you wanted

In "Format sound card driver clams to support" scroll to the bottom you get the most powerful output options here is mine example.

[image]

As Mitch said best way to check is using a oscilloscope but that's something belongs to https://electronics.stackexchange.com ...

You can also try the vb-audio software too

Link

https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm

[image]